# Unable to set up Pybrain LSTM module for Reber Grammar

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain, lstm

I'm trying to use Pybrain to predict sequences of characters belonging to the Reber grammar.

Concretely what I'm doing is generating strings using the Reber grammar graph (you can check it here : http://www.felixgers.de/papers/phd.pdf page 22). An example of such string could be BPVVE. I want my neural network to learn the underlying rules of the grammar. For each of these string I create a sequence that would typically look like this :

```
             [B, T, S, X, P, V, E,]   ,           [B, T, S, X, P, V, E,]
B -> value = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]   ,  target = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,]
P -> value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,]   ,  target = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,]
V -> value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,]   ,  target = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,]
V -> value = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,]   ,  target = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,]
E -> E is ignored for now because it marks the end
```

as you can see the value is just a 7-d vector representing the current letter and the target is the next letter in the Reber word.

Here is the code I'm trying to run :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import reberGrammar as reber
import random as rnd

from pylab import *

from pybrain.supervised          import RPropMinusTrainer
from pybrain.supervised          import BackpropTrainer

from pybrain.datasets            import SequenceClassificationDataSet
from pybrain.structure.modules   import LSTMLayer, SoftmaxLayer
from pybrain.tools.validation    import testOnSequenceData
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts     import buildNetwork

def reberToListInt(word): #e.g. "BPVVE" -> [0,4,3,3,5]
    out = [None]*len(word)

    for i,l in enumerate(word):
        if l == 'B':
            out[i] = 0
        elif l == 'T':
            out[i] = 1
        elif l == 'S':
            out[i] = 2
        elif l == 'V':
            out[i] = 3
        elif l == 'P':
            out[i] = 4
        elif l == 'E':
            out[i] = 5
        else :
            out[i] = 6

    return out

def buildReberDataSet(numSample):
    """Generate a 7 class dataset"""

    reberLexicon = reber.ReberGrammarLexicon(numSample)

    DS = SequenceClassificationDataSet(7, 7, nb_classes=7)

    for rw in reberLexicon.lexicon: 
        DS.newSequence()
        rw2 = reberToListInt(rw)
        for i in range(len(rw2)-1): #inserting one letter at a time 
            inpt = outpt = [0.0]*7
            inpt[rw2[i]]=1.0
            outpt[rw2[i+1]]=1.0
            DS.addSample(inpt,outpt)

    return DS

def printDataSet(DS, numLines): #just to print some stat
    print "\t############"
    print "Number of sequences: ",DS.getNumSequences()
    print "Input and output dimensions: ", DS.indim,"\t", DS.outdim
    print "\n"
    for i in range(numLines):
        for inp, target in DS.getSequenceIterator(i):
            print inp,
        print "\n"
    print "\t#############"

'''Dataset creation / split into training and test sets'''

fullDS = buildReberDataSet(700)

tstdata, trndata = fullDS.splitWithProportion( 0.25 )
trndata._convertToOneOfMany( bounds=[0.,1.])
tstdata._convertToOneOfMany( bounds=[0.,1.])

#printDataSet(trndata,2)

'''Network setup / training'''

rnn = buildNetwork( trndata.indim, 7, trndata.outdim, hiddenclass=LSTMLayer, outclass=SoftmaxLayer, outputbias=False, recurrent=True)
trainer = RPropMinusTrainer( rnn, dataset=trndata, verbose=True )
#trainer = BackpropTrainer( rnn, dataset=trndata, verbose=True, momentum=0.9, learningrate=0.5 ) 

trainError=[]
testError =[]

#errors = trainer.trainUntilConvergence()


for i in range(9):
    trainer.trainEpochs( 2 )
    trainError.append(100. * (1.0-testOnSequenceData(rnn, trndata)))
    testError.append(100. * (1.0-testOnSequenceData(rnn, tstdata)))
    print "train error: %5.2f%%" % trainError[i], ",  test error: %5.2f%%" % testError[i]

plot(trainError)
hold(True)
plot(testError)
show()
```

I fail to train this net. The errors are fluctuating a lot and there is no real convergence. I would really appreciate some advises on this.

Here is the code I'm using to generate Reber strings :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random as rnd

class ReberGrammarLexicon(object):

    lexicon = set() #contain Reber words
    graph = [ [(1,'T'), (5,'P')], \
            [(1, 'S'), (2, 'X')], \
            [(3,'S') ,(5, 'X')],  \
            [(6, 'E')],           \
            [(3, 'V'),(2, 'P')],  \
            [(4, 'V'), (5, 'T')] ]  #store the graph

    def __init__(self, num, maxSize = 1000): #fill Lexicon with num words

        self.maxSize = maxSize

        if maxSize < 5:
            raise NameError('maxSize too small, require maxSize > 4') 

        while len(self.lexicon) < num:

            word = self.generateWord()
            if word != None:
                self.lexicon.add(word)

    def generateWord(self): #generate one word

        c = 2
        currentEdge = 0
        word = 'B'

        while c <= self.maxSize:

            inc = rnd.randint(0,len(self.graph[currentEdge])-1)
            nextEdge = self.graph[currentEdge][inc][0]
            word += self.graph[currentEdge][inc][1]
            currentEdge = nextEdge
            if currentEdge == 6 :
                break
            c+=1

        if c > self.maxSize :
            return None

        return word
```

Thanks,

Best